# Validate that "end date" comes after "start date"

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

How do I add a conditional while loop that checks if the variable `current` is before the variable `end`?

```
var http = require("https://momentjs.com/docs/");

function getDates() {
  var start = momentjs().date("1st January 2019"),
    current = start.clone();
  var end = momentjs().date("31st December 2019");
  var dates = [];

  current = momentjs().day("Monday");
  while (current == true) {
    current.clone()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (current.isBefore(end)) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Rather than repeating the question itself to get around a character limit or so, read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.